# Ionic Cordova Firebase Facebook login error: "Sorry, something went wrong. We are working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can"

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic4

I'm trying to login users with Facebook and Firebase, I have followed the documentation and some tutorials but I cannot make it work. I'm having this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOBNQ.jpg)

Plugin version:
**"cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^6.4.0",**
Also:
**"cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
"APP_ID": "47************",
"APP_NAME": "Mimas"
},**

My code:

```
public authWithFacebook(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        await this.facebook.login(['public_profile']).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
          this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            resolve(response);
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(this.translate.get(err.code));
          });
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log("ERROR =========>");
          console.log(err);
          reject();
        });
      } else {
        console.log("ELSEEEEEE =========>");
        const fbprovider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(fbprovider).then(res => {
          resolve(res);
        }).catch((e) => {
          reject(e);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```